# limit custom html.tpl.php to exact page, not subpages, drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

I have a custom tpl page intended for a specific page like so:

html--something--anotherthing.tpl.php

This allows some custom handling on the page /something/anotherthing as desired. Unfortunately it is also being applied to sub pages like /something/anotherthing/details where the custom handling is not desired. Is there a syntax for naming tpl files so that it only applies to the desired page?

edit: I've enabled theme_debug and it suggests exactly what I already have for the filename so not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just one page you can just use something like `node--nid.tpl.php`
 or `page--node--nid.tpl.php` right? (Assume that `/something/anotherthing` and `/something/anotherthing/details` are two difference nodes)

Comment: The question mentions page but the example template file names suggest OP is overriding the html template rather than page. It's the same deal, just `html--node--1.tpl.php` instead of `page--...`

Comment: The page in question isn't a node. More of a custom page full of mini panels.

Answer (score 1):

If /something/anotherthing is a node, the answer by cchen has you covered. In case it's not...

The base suggestions are built up in [`theme_get_suggestions`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7.x), (called by [`template_preprocess_html`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7.x)), and mirror the path and its parents. So for a path of /foo/bar/baz, you'll automatically have:

- html
- html__foo
- html__foo__bar
- html__foo__bar__baz

You can approach changing that in a couple of different ways:

1. Don't use the built-in suggestions, create your own:

   ```
   function MYMODULE_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
     // Example only, if you have a better way to determine the path, use it!
     if (request_uri() == '/something/anotherthing') {
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'] = 'something__anotherthing';
     }
   }
   ```

   A template file named `something--anotherthing.tpl.php` would be picked up for that path only.
2. Remove the built-in suggestion for the parent when visiting the child:

   ```
   function MYMODULE_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
     if (request_uri() == '/something/anotherthing/details') {
       $index = array_search('html__something__anotherthing', $vars['theme_hook_suggestions']);

       if ($index !== FALSE) {
         unset($vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][$index]);
       }
     } 
   }
   ```

   This method is probably best as an example only, as you'll have to remember to add more exceptions to the code as you add new pages under /something/anotherthing.

Both examples can also be implemented in a theme if that's preferable.

Comment: Yep this is the way to go if you want to have templates based on path alias.

Comment: I definitely want something I won't have to edit for future sub-pages but I think this will get me in the right direction. Will play around with it and accept this when I get it working.